# Python: Is there any way to monitor Drag and Drop events in Windows?

Tags: python, winapi

I am designing a software in Python. I want a way to monitor drag and drop (files/folders) events in Windows OS from one Windows explorer to another Windows explorer and get the list of dropped file paths in return and then run some functions automatically.
**Actually I want to Overwrite the Default Action of Windows os Drag and Drop Event method with my own python script Method**
Is this possible from within Python?